# Conditional Group By CASE statement

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements, case

Consider the Table

```
 count | lat | lng | Date
 ------+-----+-----+------
   1   | 10  | 21  | 01/12
   1   | 10  | 21  | 01/12
   1   | 20  | 25  | 02/12
   1   | 30  | 31  | 02/12
   1   | 30  | 31  | 02/12
   1   | 10  | 21  | 03/12
```

The above table contains latitude/longitude by date. I want to group the lat/lng over a date

e.g. for date 01/12, the count will become 2 for lat/lng 10/21, then for the next record(3rd) it will be 1, and for 4th & 5th, it will become 2 for the date 02/12.

```
 count | lat | lng | Date
 ------+-----+-----+------
   2   | 10  | 21  | 01/12
   1   | 20  | 25  | 02/12
   2   | 30  | 31  | 02/12
   1   | 10  | 21  | 03/12
```

I can neither group by 'date', nor by 'lat/lng' combination. Only a conditional group by statement can solve it (maybe) otherwise I have to divide & conquer! Anyone has the solution for such statement?

using MySQL 5

Comment: Would not grouping by all 3 work, date first, then lat/long.

Comment: @Orbling: Column order in a `GROUP BY` clause doesn't matter

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I was implying that the ordering thereafter would need to be that way.  I note your answer did as I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to provide information -- table(s) involved (including column data types) -- for us to know why the following doesn't work for you:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count,
         t.lat,
         t.lng,
         t.date
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.lat, t.lng, t.date
```